# Show this series diverges to infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$a_n = \frac{3^n}{n^k}$ for all natural numbers $n$.
Show that for all $k\in N$,   $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = \infty.$

Answer (score 2):

$3^n>e^n= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^j}{j!}> \frac{n^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$, thus

$\frac{3^n}{n^k}> \frac{n}{(k+1)!}$

Comment: Or $3^n=(1+2)^n>\binom{n}{k+1}2^{k+1}\ge\frac{n^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$ for $n\ge 2k$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$\forall n>0\; a_n>0$

$\forall n>0\;\; \ln(a_n)=n(\ln(3)-k\frac{\ln(n)}{n})$

You can finish it.